# Is there a nonlinear counterpart of multicollinearity?

Tags: multicollinearity, nonlinear-regression

Is there a nonlinear counterpart of multicolinearity. i.e. if two variables x1 and x2 are nonlinearly dependent on eachother in such a way that makes interpretation the coefficients of a specific nonlinear model using these two variables problematic?

Comment: [How to test for multicollinearity among non-linearly related independent variables](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/63730/how-to-test-for-multicollinearity-among-non-linearly-related-independent-variabl)

Comment: Thanks for your comment! The question is a bit different as I'm looking for a nonlinear counterpart of multicollinearity, the questions asked in the link is about standard multicollinearity in nonlinear regression.

Comment: "Linearly dependent" has a precise meaning.  "Nonlinearly dependent" means, literally, *everything else.*  There cannot possibly be any general counterpart.  In particular, "nonlinear model" is far too broad to have any useful meaning here.  Do you have some specific form of "nonlinearity" or some specific model in mind?  That might make this an answerable question.